# Using class to return difenet text structure

Tags: python, class, micropython

To save space I do not have my "class" here. This is a representative of what I need.
I would like to get a form like text from a class.

```
class my_class:
    def _my_base(my_def_text, title, description):
        rtn = ['this is a test',
               '',
               'some text',
               f'      {title}',
               '      this is some text that is needed',
               f'      {description}',
               f'{my_def_text}'
               ]
        return "\n".join(rtn)
    def first_text(value):
        title = 'First text'
        description = "this is a test"
        rtn = ['red',
               '',
               'green',
               'blue',
               f'      {value}',
               ]
        return _my_base("\n".join(rtn), title, description)
    def second_text(value):
        title = 'second text'
        description = "this is a test"
        rtn = ['      some text',
               f'      {value}',
               '',
               'This is to show that I want the text in different places',
               ]
        return _my_base("\n".join(rtn), title, description)
```

If I try:

```
>>> my_test = my_class
>>> my_test.first_text("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in first_text
NameError: name '_my_base' is not defined
```

This is what I get.
What I wanted

this is a test

some text
First text
this is some text that is needed
this is a test
red

green
blue
hello

I did try **init** with less luck.
Tried "self" and it said that self was not defined.

Comment: a class method needs at least one param, but convention this is `self`. So if you want to have `value` as an input then you would need `def first_text(self, value):` ....

Comment: it might be helpful to have a quick read of this:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html  or maybe a book with the same (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BHL2XKCR)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I neded the () for the class call!!

```
class my_class:
    def my_base(self, my_def_text, title, description):
        rtn = ['this is a test',
               '',
               'some text',
               f'      {title}',
               '      this is some text that is needed',
               f'      {description}',
               f'{my_def_text}'
               ]
        return "\n".join(rtn)
    def first_text(value):
        title = 'First text'
        description = "this is a test"
        rtn = ['red',
               '',
               'green',
               'blue',
               f'      {value}',
               ]
        return _my_base("\n".join(rtn), title, description)
    def second_text(self, value):
        title = 'second text'
        description = "this is a test"
        rtn = ['      some text',
               f'      {value}',
               ]
        return self._my_base("\n".join(rtn), title, description)

my_text = my_class()
my_class.first_text('hello')
```